# What is the source for a woman's voice as ervah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, tznius-modesty, song-poetry

What is the source that a woman's (singing) voice is considered ervah?

Comment: Why do you have "singing" in parenthesis? Are you looking for a source for her voice or her singing voice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Gemara Berachos 24a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=24&format=pdf) : Shmuel says that kol of a women is ervah because of the passuk in [shir hashirim 2:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16446/showrashi/true#v14).

> יד. יוֹנָתִי בְּחַגְוֵי הַסֶּלַע בְּסֵתֶר הַמַּדְרֵגָה הַרְאִינִי אֶת מַרְאַיִךְ הַשְׁמִיעִנִי אֶת קוֹלֵךְ **כִּי קוֹלֵךְ עָרֵב וּמַרְאֵיךְ נָאוֶה**:‏
>
> My dove, in the clefts of the rock, in the coverture of the steps, show me your appearance, let me hear your voice, **for your voice is pleasant and your appearance is comely.**'

Comment: I'm wondering how we know that this applies to singing and not speaking (re: ervah)?

Comment: The Divrei Yatziv goes through this inyun,he does bring shittos who seem to hold that an esheis ish speaking voice is assur,the Mieri for one

Comment: @sah I think that is a fair question to ask separately

Answer (score 7):

[Yerushalmi Challah 12b](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1902.htm) : Shmuel says that kol of a women is ervah because of the passuk in [yirmiyahu 3:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16000/showrashi/true#v9).

> ט. וְהָיָה **מִקֹּל זְנוּתָהּ וַתֶּחֱנַף אֶת הָאָרֶץ** וַתִּנְאַף אֶת הָאֶבֶן וְאֶת הָעֵץ:‏
>
> And it was through the **voice** [lit. lightness] **of her harlotry, that she polluted the land**, and she committed adultery with the stones and the wood.

Comment: nice find,I wonder why Shmuel gave to diff sources.

Comment: @shmuelbrin All editions of the Talmud Yerushlami that I can find now online denote the opening of the Amoraic discussion of the Mishna with 'גמ.

Comment: @DoubleAA they do, but I think that this is clearer.