# Kol Ishah through filters

Tags: technology, kol-isha, recording

***According to the opinions that one [may not listen to a woman's recording](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44305/9682):***

I've been playing around with some music recording programs, particularly the functions that modulate the voice and apply filters to make it sound different. This got me thinking: what if a man sang and applied these filters to make his voice sound like a woman's? What about the opposite, a woman singing and modulating her voice to sound like a man's? Is there a kol ishah issue in either case? That is, do we go after who's singing, or what it sounds like on the recording?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27206/759

Comment: All you've discovered is why those opinions don't make any sense. Once you're out of a technical prohibition of coming close to an actual woman, the only rule left is don't do things that can cause improper thoughts. Recorded women's voices may be that. As could avocados. It just depends on the situation.

Comment: @DoubleAA Interesting you might say that, as it's actually my minhag to follow those machmir opinions. I guess I'll have to ask my rav if it's a minhag ta'us...

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure how much this question "parrots" that one (ugh). After all, you know for certain that it's *not* the woman singing. You have no idea what's going on behind the CD.

Comment: "You know for certain" Huh? Neither question specified whether or not you know how the thing was created.

Comment: @DoubleAA I meant in the parrot case you can see it's the parrot singing, not the woman. Here, "you have no idea what's going on behind the CD."

Comment: I don't know why you assume the person sees the parrot. Maybe it's background music at a restaurant.

Comment: Also possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55709/759

Comment: Given that according to [R. Moshe Feinstein and many others](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2012/02/answers-to-quiz-questions-and-other.html) the prohibition is only on an erotic experience, then one would be fine as long as he is not aroused.

Comment: @mevaqesh I figured as much, based on the discussions on here regarding shemiras einayim. But does that mean that even listening to a *man* who sounds like a woman would be assur, if it's arousing?

Comment: @DonielF Yes. One is not allowed to arouse oneself. This is the case whether it involves singing or avocado eating. According to many authorities, however, there may be a separate issue with women's voices in certain contexts when one is reciting the Shema; see the link above.