Kol Isha applicable to AI generated music?
Does Kol Isha apply to songs generated by AI?
For instance, there's a website https://www.udio.com that allows one to generate music. If a female singer who doesn't even exist is singing, is a man allowed to listen? Additional to the fact that its technically not live.

Would you still be asking if it was artificial generated images instead of voices?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75834/kol-ishah-through-filters?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment221953_75834

Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55709/759

There are two different prohibitions related to intimacy:

One is Biblical and relates to Arayos (illicit relations), see Mishneh Torah Negative Mitzvot.353:


שלא ליקרב לעריות בדברים המביאין לידי גילוי ערווה,
;כגון חיבוק ונישוק ורמיזה וקפיצה, שנאמר "אל כל שאר בשרו, לא תקרבו לגלות ערווה" (ויקרא יח,ו)


Not to "approach intimately" a woman (with whom sexual relations are forbidden) in matters that might lead to intercourse - e.g., embracing, kissing, winks, or signs - as [Leviticus 18:6] states: "No person shall approach a close relative to commit a sexual offense.”


The second is Rabbinic (and especially Kabbalistic) and relates to ritual impurity (wasting seed), see Niddah.13a.

In Berakhot.24a, Rabbis define different parts of a woman's body as Ervah, such as her leg, hair, or voice. (I presume here that the use of the word Ervah points to the first prohibition rather than the second, although the subject of the discussion is reading Shema against nudity.)
Therefore we should conclude:

regarding the first prohibition, only the natural parts of a specific woman are considered Ervah (exposure) and are forbidden, e.g., buying wigs, pads, or pantyhose, or studying women's anatomy are not. Therefore, only listening to a real singing woman (without amplifiers) would be prohibited, and as long as we can't be intimate with AI, listening to generated voices would be permitted. See also here.

regarding the second, it is a matter of cultural norms and personal propensities. E.g. the Gemmorah (Niddah.13b) prohibits men from wearing pants as causing [nocturnal] emission, but practices change, and we not only wear pants but underpants as well. Therefore, in Western civilization, where women's singing is not considered erotic, it would not be prohibited, but in Islamic countries where it is rare, and considered erotic, it would be prohibited.


