Kol Isha with adjusted pitch/chipmunked
What is the Halacha regarding Kol Isha if the music piece in question is adjusted to either raise or lower the pitch?
For example, playing the same music piece a few octaves lower can make a woman sound manly or vice versa, or make someone sound like a chipmunk if raised higher.

She could also breathe in helium, or argon between stanzas

+1 Good point, esp. with the new AI song generators. Well, if wigs work, any non-natural female voice should too, shouldn't it?

Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75834/kol-ishah-through-filters?
