# According to Rov Eliyashiv Maran Ovadia Yosef and the Tzitz Eliezer would listening to recorded songs with messages contrary to Judaism be permitted?

Tags: hacham-ovadia-yosef, kol-isha

According to all three of them, hearing a recording of a woman sing does not constitute as kol isha because recordings are simply airwaves transmitting electric sounds as opposed to the woman's actual voice. Could this leniency possibly extend to recordings of songs that would normally be forbidden such as songs with sexual lyrics or church music?

Comment: Do you have the sources for this?

Comment: You can make the same extension to pictures of naked people.

Comment: @Dov https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44314/759 it's really pashut

Comment: @DoubleAA - I'm not debating whether it is poshut or not I was just asking to firm up the question by adding in the sources.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5794/sources-for-listening-to-not-listening-to-non-jewish-music