# Why should the voice of a woman be viewed as being different than that of a man, for the sake of "singing in public"?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, kol-isha

Why should the voice of a woman be viewed as being different (according to Jewish Law) than that of a man, for the sake of "singing in public"?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22491/what-is-the-source-for-a-womans-voice-as-ervah

Comment: I'm voting to close as a dupe for @rosends' link, but I'm tempted to flag this as a rant in disguise.

Comment: @msh210  wadr, I liked this question way better as originally expressed by the OP.

Comment: @Loewian, with the rant in it? Curious. Well, I don't need to have the last word here: anyone can edit.

Answer (score 1):

You ask why a woman's voiceshould be treated differently to a man's voice. The referenced question “[What is the source for a woman's voice as ervah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22491/what-is-the-source-for-a-womans-voice-as-ervah)” provides you with the material for an answer. A woman's voice is considered as “ervah”.

The [Wikipedia article on tzniut - modesty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzniut) refers to dress, hair covering and the female singing voice and discusses its relevance to ervah.

It seems that the  female singing voice has a similar categorisation as immodest dress or hair-covering. Evidently the male voice does not have the same qualities.

So the issue does not relate to the voice in the active service of G-d, but rather to not using the voice in order to serve G-d's will.